# How to make a bootstrap carousel with a caption on the right hand side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make the caption be on the right-hand side. However, it just aligns on the left-hand side.

The CSS:

```
#jumboCarousel {
    margin-top: 70px;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 600px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
#jumboCarousel img {
    min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 600px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
#jumboCarousel > .carousel-indicators > li {
    border-radius: 0px;
    min-width: 25px;
    background-color: #9d9d9d;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 10px;;
    margin-left: 10px;;
}
#jumboCarousel > .carousel-indicators > .active {
    background-color: orange;
}
#jumboCarousel .carousel-caption {
    color: white;
    xright: 58%;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 300px;
    right: 0;
    top: 1px;
  /*top: 50%; */
  xtransform: translateY(-50%);
  xbottom: initial;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding:10px;
  height:100%;

}

.item {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
```

The codepen to my problem is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/VdeGYK?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `left: auto;` to `#jumboCarousel .carousel-caption`

```
#jumboCarousel .carousel-caption {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 300px;
    right: 0;
    top: 1px;
    xtransform: translateY(-50%);
    xbottom: initial;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    left: auto; /*Added*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that there is a left:20%; value in the .carousel-caption class.

The solution is to add left:initial;

```
    #jumboCarousel .carousel-caption {left:initial;}
```